# Spring Boot Security - Thymeleaf sec:authorize not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use Spring Boot, Spring Security 4, Thymeleaf.And if the user has role"admin" or anything else.The html block should be shown up.But now it always display on the page.
Here is my html

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_GUEST')">
    <p class="bg-info">guest</p>
    </div>
    <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        <p class="bg-info">you can see this if you have permission to acess role_admin</p>
    </div>
```

And here is my pom.xml i do add the thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4. Also tried thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.zhongdihang.resp</groupId>
        <artifactId>resp-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../resp-parent</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>resp-serve</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Real estate sharing platform serve</name>
    <description>Real estate sharing platform serve</description>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zhongdihang.resp</groupId>
            <artifactId>resp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zhongdihang.resp</groupId>
            <artifactId>resp-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Optional -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here is my securityconfig

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;


    @Autowired
    private SecurityUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return provider;
    }

    @Value("${" + ApplicationConstants.THIS_APP_CONFIG_PREFIX + ".security.debug:false}")
    private boolean debug = false;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    private void configureExceptionHandling(ExceptionHandlingConfigurer<HttpSecurity> handler) {
        handler.authenticationEntryPoint(new SecurityAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    }
    private void configureAuthorizeRequests(ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry registry) {
        //registry.accessDecisionManager(new SecurityAccessDecisionManager());      
        registry.antMatchers("/login/**","/auth/**","/api/open/person/**","/api/booking/**","/api/module/menu","/api/booking").permitAll();
        List<RoleEntity> list = roleService.findAll();
        for (RoleEntity roleEntity : list) {
            if(roleEntity.getModule()!=null) {
                registry.antMatchers(roleEntity.getModule().getPath()+"/**").hasAuthority(roleEntity.getNumber()).anyRequest().authenticated();
            }
        }
        registry.anyRequest().authenticated();
        //registry.anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMINISTRATOR");
    }

    private void configureFilter(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         //http.addFilterBefore(new SecurityAuthorizationFilter(sessionrepo),
         //UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        configureFilter(http);
        configureExceptionHandling(http.exceptionHandling());
        configureAuthorizeRequests(http.authorizeRequests());
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .failureHandler(new SecurityAauthenticationFailureHandler())
            .successHandler(new SecurityAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .permitAll();
        http.logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new SecurityLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.debug(debug);
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**.ico");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs");
    }
}
```

Anybody can help me?
thank you so much~

Comment: `.But now it always display on the page` is it the `login` page?

Comment: this element was written on index.html.And i can see both of messages.But the user don't have any roles.

Comment: I cannot find `configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method. is a `jdbcAuthentication` an acceptable solution for you?

Comment: @Autowired
     public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
      auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
     }    is this what u were looking for?

Comment: maybe but i guess it should be  called `configAuthentication`. But, unfortunatlly, i haven't work with `userDetailsService`. instead i can help you with `jdbcAuthentication`. would it be helpfull?

Comment: well,thank you for your answers.But i don't think that i can change userDetailsService to jdbcAuthtication.The project was build by manager.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using springboot `1.5.8.RELEASE` thymeleaf `3.0.9.RELEASE`,so i need to use latest `org.thymeleaf.extras`.so try to add

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

in you pom.

Answer (score 0):

WHat you are missing here is a tag in your HTML

`xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"`.

You don't really need `xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"` tag anyways if you're using Springboot.