# Thymeleaf security is not working although no errors

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

So somehow all security things in the html files don't work. No matter if I use `sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"` or `sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"`, the content will always be displayed.
I took a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920822/spring-boot-security-thymeleaf-secauthorize-not-working), which is quite similar, but his security is different and the thread was never answered, same with other posts.

I am using the latest version of the security addon (here is the dependency):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

along with spring boot 2.1.2.
I am absolutly clueless what is causing this. In my other projects this has worked out fine and I can't seem to spot the difference!

**Edit:**
Here is my complete POM:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.theden</groupId>
  <artifactId>the-den-website</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>the-den-website</name>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
      <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
          <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
          <version>LATEST</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.4</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.197</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>true</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>net.endrealm.website.Application</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the version to 3.0.4.RELEASE?

Comment: Yeah. But latest does the same. Intellij shows me that the library is found and uses 3.0.4

Comment: Could you provide your pom.xml to see your other dependencies?

Comment: Just added the pom

Comment: What about using thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5?

Comment: Didn't look into that yet... Any major changes?

Comment: Not that I know. But I view it without being logged in. Despite that hasRole doesn't work either